# Update multiple variables based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, duration, event, starttime and finishtime. Duration, starttime and finishtime are integers while event is a string e.g Component 1 failed, Component 2 repaired etc. Duration, starttime and finish time describe the duration of an event, the starttime of the event and the finishtime of the event. What I want to do is to update specific variables based on time. For example, I am creating a for loop and iterate over the dataframe, when component 1 failed then a specific variable must be updated to False, then if in the second cycle component 5 repaired then a specific variable must be updated to True, then if on the third cycle component 3 failed then a specific variable must be updated to False (so now we have 2 false, component 1 and component 3). If on the fourth cycle component 1 is repaired then the specific variable must be updated to True (now only component 3 is false).

Example of the dataframe:

| Duration | EventLog | StartTime | FinishTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Component 1 repaired | 0 | 12 |
| 5 | Component 3 Failed | 0 | 5 |
| 12 | Component 5 Failed | 12 | 24 |
| 44 | Component 1 Repaired | 55 | 99 |

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
for i in range(8760):
    if 'Repaired' in data.loc[i,'EventLog'] :
        val = int(re.search(r'\d+', data.loc[i,'EventLog']).group())
        if val >= 0 and val <= 9:
            net.gen.loc[val,"in_service"] = True
        else:
            val = val - 10
            net.line.loc[val,"in_service"] = True        
        
    elif 'Failed' in data.loc[i,'EventLog'] :
        val = int(re.search(r'\d+', data.loc[i,'EventLog']).group())
        if val >= 0 and val <= 9:
            net.gen.loc[val,"in_service"] = False
        else:
            val = val - 10
            net.line.loc[val,"in_service"] = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how large a DataFrame you are dealing with, but this approach will work for most frames:

```
def findCondition(val:str, schWord: str) -> bool:
    # returns True if val contains schWord, else False
    return schWord.lower() in val.lower()
```

You can then add a new column to the frame using:

```
df['Operate'] = [findCondition(x, 'Repaired') for x in df['EventLog '].to_list()]
```

Which produces:

```
  Duration  EventLog      StartTime FinishTime  Operate
0   12  Component 1 repaired    0   12          True
1   5   Component 3 Failed      0    5          False
2   12  Component 5 Failed      12  24          False
3   44  Component 1 Repaired    55  99          True
```

​

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works partially, my main issue is that I want to keep track of time. for example in the example above component 3 must be False for 5 iterations and then back to True.

Comment: 5 iterations of what?  This aspect is not apparent from your question, nor your example.  Please update the question showing exactly what you expect the output to be.